# Are these two antiderivatives equivalent?

Tags: calculus, integration

Regarding the anti derivative of: $\cos^3\left(x\right)\sin^3\left(x\right)$

Is the answer $-\dfrac{\sin^4\left(x\right)\left(2\sin^2\left(x\right)-3\right)}{12}$ equivalent to $\dfrac{\sin^4\left(x\right)}{4}$

If so, how? Integral Calculator says they're equivalent, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are antiderivatives of the same  function, then their difference will be constant.

But their difference is $-\dfrac{\sin^6x}{6}$ which is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is indeed an antiderivatives of $\cos^3(x)\sin^3(x)$. But if you differentiate the second one, what you get is $\cos(x)\sin^3(x)$, rather than $\cos^3(x)\sin^3(x)$.

Comment: I’d rephrase that first sentence. It reads as contradicting the second sentence. Just saying, “one of those is not an anti-derivative” might be better.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nice suggestion. I've edited my answer.